# Expected minimum size of multinomial distribution that includes at least one value of each class

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

Suppose I have a vector and I include a new item on it at every time step. This item has one of $k$ different classes, each class has probability $\frac{1}{k}$ of being selected.

Suppose now I stop when my vector has at least one item of each of the $k$ classes and let's call the length of this complete vector $n$.

What is the expected value of n?

Comment: I think this is the coupon collector problem, unless I'm misinterpreting the question.